# Facebook messenger bot error Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to create a Facebook messenger bot using NodeJS and Express.

I'm following the [facebook guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started) and when I tried to run this command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:4000/" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}'
```

I have got this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0`

Here is my code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var request = require("request")

    var app = express();
    var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === '22222') {
            res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
            console.log("GET")
            res.sendStatus(200)
        }

        console.log("Error: wrong token")
    })

    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
        console.log("post")
        for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
            event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
            sender = event.sender.id;
            if (event.message && event.message.text) {
                text = event.message.text;
                sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: " + text.substring(0, 200));
            }
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });

    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
    });

    var token = "<token>";

    function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
        messageData = {
            text: text
        }
        request({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
            qs: { access_token: token },
            method: 'POST',
            json: {
                recipient: { id: sender },
                message: messageData,
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
            } else if (response.body.error) {
                console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

I ignored this error and started the bot. Webhooks I connected via ngrok. I'm sure that on Facebook I set everything right.But I'm not getting the message information sent to my webhook from facebook.]

Edit: `'{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}'` this is the error line

Comment: Do you get a line number as well about where the error occurs?

Comment: try using messenger-bot npm package

Comment: @EdwinBabu I tried much of packages and no does not work

Comment: I tested the code and its working properly for me.

Comment: @EdwinBabu Can you please say me how did you set up messenger on facebook?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:4000/" -d "{""object"": ""page"", ""entry"": [{""messaging"": [{""message"": ""TEST_MESSAGE""}]}]}"
```

Comment: provide some explanation.

Comment: In windows command prompt, we use " to quote a string instead of ', and use double quote "" to escape ", at least I got the same problem but solved by this way

Comment: @ZephyrLee I was having trouble with this for a while and then I managed to find this question. Thank you, the changes to the quotes worked as well with the updated version of the tutorial. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:4000/webhook" -d "{\"object\": \"page\", \"entry\": [{\"messaging\": [{\"message\":\"TEST_MESSAGE\"}]}]}"
```

use \" because the json parser needs the double quote(" ") for json parsing here we are passing

single quote(' ') that's why the parser failed to parse the json that we are passing

`"{\"object\": \"page\", \"entry\": [{\"messaging\": [{\"message\":\"TEST_MESSAGE\"}]}]}"`

check this out this will work.

Thanks